# What happens if more than one ResourceQuota is enabled per namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, resources, limit, quota

The Kubernetes documentation says:

> The administrator creates one `ResourceQuota` for each namespace.

However, Kubernetes API does not prevent from creating more than one `ResourceQuota` per namespace.

**What happens if I have two `ResourceQuota`s in one namespace?** Which one is used? The one with lower limits or the one with higher limits?

I cannot find the answer without testing it, which takes some time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's true, it's possible to create multiple ResourceQuota in the same namespace and it has been mentioned in few cases in [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23698). It's important to remember that the ResourceQuota is one of the Admission Controllers turned on by default as per [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#resourcequota):

> This admission controller will observe the incoming request and ensure that it does not violate any of the constraints enumerated in the ResourceQuota object in a Namespace.

That means that regardless of the number of ResourceQuotas in the same namespace, if they are all meeting the requirements it'll be fine. A problem will occur if there will be any ResourceQuota/s which is/are violating the requirements and than it'll simply fail.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor the answer is OK, but not obvious. Seems like I should have given an example in my question to get a clear yes/no answer. So, if I have **spec.hard.limits.cpu: "100"** in one ResourceQuota object and **spec.hard.limits.cpu: "10"** in another ResourceQuota object, it would mean OK for total CPU < 10. Total CPU usage above 10 would break one of the ResourceQuotas constraints. SO, the answer to my question: **The one with lower limits**
Or better answer : the solution is AND (the common subset) not OR (the sum of sets)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hands-on answer, I just tested myself with the following yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: "high-quota"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: 1000m
    requests.memory: 0.5G
    limits.cpu: 1000m
    limits.memory: 0.5G
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: "low-quota"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: 1000m
    requests.memory: 0.1G
    limits.cpu: 1000m
    limits.memory: 0.1G
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "hello"
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: "hello"
      image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "0.4G"
          cpu: "1000m"
        limits:
          memory: "0.4G"
          cpu: "1000m"
```

It is the lower limit that will be prioritized.

```
❯ kubectl apply -f .\resources-quotas.yaml
    resourcequota/high-quota created
    resourcequota/low-quota created
    Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating ".\\resources-quotas.yaml": pods "hello" is forbidden: exceeded quota: demo2, requested: limits.memory=400M,requests.memory=400M, used: limits.memory=0,requests.memory=0, limited: limits.memory=100M,requests.memory=100M
```